# RXJS expand operator

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rets

```
var offset = 1;
var limit = 500;

var list = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  rets.getAutoLogoutClient(config.clientSettings, (client) => {
    var results = client.search.query(SearchType, Class, Query, {
      limit: limit,
      offset: offset
    });
    resolve(results);
  });
});

var source = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(list);

source.subscribe(results => console.log(results.count));
```

I am doing a real estate site, using RETS.

What I am trying to do my query are limited from the RETS server, is run this in a loop increasing my Offset until I have all my data. I don't know what the count is until I run the query and find the count value.

I have tried to use expand but I have no clue of how exactly it works. Tried to do these multiple ways, even using the old fashion while loop, which while doesn't work with .then method. So I have turned to RXJS since I been using it in Angular 4.

This is done in express. I need to eventually run corn jobs to fetch for updated properties, but my problem is fetching all the data and increasing the offset each time if the count is higher than my offset. So for example, run a query with an offset of 1 with a limit of 500. Total here is 1690. So next go around my offset would be:

```
offset += limit
```

Once I have my data, I need to save it to MongoDB. Which I already been able successfully to do. It's just finding a way to get all the data without having to manually set my offset.

Note the server limit is 2500, yes I can fetch all this in one shot but there are also other data, such as media, which could have well over 2500.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a fairly common use case for RxJS, as there are a lot of paginated data sources, or sources that are otherwise limited in what you can request at one time.

**My two cents**

To my mind `expand` is probably the best operator for this given that you are paginating against an unknown data source and you require at least one query in order to determine the final count. If you knew how much data you were going to be querying a more easier option would be to use something like `mergeScan`, but I digress.

**Proposed Solution**

This may take a little effort to wrap your head around so I have added annotations wherever possible to break down how this all works. *Note* I haven't actually tested this, so forgive me any syntax errors.

```
// Your constant limit for any one query
const limit = 500;

// RxJS helper method that wraps the async call into an Observable
// I am basing this on what I saw of your sample which leads me to believe
// that this should work. 
const clientish = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(rets.getAutoLogoutClient);

// A method wrapper around your query call that wraps the resulting promise
// into a defer.
const queryish = (client, params) =>
  // Note the use of defer here is deliberate, since the query returns
  // a promise that will begin executing immediately, this prevents that behavior
  // And forces execution on subscription.
  Rx.Observable.defer(() => client.search.query(SearchType, Class, Query, params));

// This does the actual expansion function
// Note this is a higher order function because the client and the parameters
// are available at different times
const expander = (client) => ({limit, count}) => 
  // Invoke the query method
  queryish(client, {limit, count})
    // Remap the results, update offset and count and forward the whole 
    // package down stream
    .map(results => ({
      limit, 
      count: results.count, 
      offset: offset + limit, 
      results
    }));


// Start the stream by constructing the client
clientish(config.clientSettings)
  .switchMap(client =>
     // This are the arguments for the initial call
     Rx.Observable.of({limit, offset: 0})
       // Call the expander function with the client
       // The second argument is the max concurrency, you can change that if needed
       .expand(expander(client), 1)

       // Expand will keep recursing unless you tell it to stop
       // This will halt the execution once offset exceeds count, i.e. you have
       // all the data
       .takeWhile(({count, offset}) => offset < count)

       // Further downstream you only care about the results
       // So extract them from the message body and only forward them
       .pluck('results')
  )
  .subscribe(results => /*Do stuff with results*/);
```

Comment: This does not work. switchMap not a function. takeWhile has syntax errors, the rets client stuff needs to be combined better.

Comment: @JoshuaScott which version of RxJS are you using?

Comment: I am using RXJS 5

Answer (score 0):

```
const retsConnect = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
  rets.getAutoLogoutClient(config.clientSettings, client => {
    return searchQuery(client, 500, 1, observer);
  });
});

function searchQuery(client, limit, offset, observer) {
  let currentOffset = offset === undefined || offset === 0 ? 1 : offset;
  return client.search.query(SearchType, Class, Query, {limit: limit, offset: currentOffset})
    .then(results => {
      offset += limit;
      observer.next(results.maxRowsExceeded);
      if (results.maxRowsExceeded) {
        console.log(offset);
        return searchQuery(client, limit, offset, observer);
      } else {
        console.log('Completed');
        observer.complete();
      }
    });
}

retsConnect.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

So this is getting somewhere with what I have tried here. I am still in process of tweaking this. So what I am looking to do is break the searchQuery down more. Not sure if I should be passing observer.next there, so I am going to is figure out where to map and takeUntil install of returning searchQuery again. I'm not sure takeUntil will take a true or false though. All I need this data to do is be saved into mongodb. So I guess I could leave it like this and have my save method put in there, but I still like to figure this out.

Note: results.maxRowsExceeded returns true when there are still more data. So once the maxRows returns false, it will stop and all the data has been fetched.